# How to reliably recieve message from AWS that my instance was rebooted / terminated / stopped?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have Nagios, and I want it to stop monitoring instances when they are stopped from the console. The requirements are:

1. The message passed from AWS is 100R% reliable, e.g. when Nagios is down, and the message cannot be delivered, it will be re-delivered promptly when Nagios is up
2. The message will pass quickly
3. There is no need to scan status of all instances via EC2 API all the time, but only once a while

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you keep up with Nagios/Capistrano configs when using EC2?](http://serverfault.com/questions/377944/how-do-you-keep-up-with-nagios-capistrano-configs-when-using-ec2)

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I am looking specifically into passing the event - message - reliably. There is no reason why it's not possible. It makes difference because of time-constrainsts.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is no way to do it. The solution is to use Cloud Watch. But by polling the AWS API it is possible to add dedicated instance which will update Nagios. But it has to work with polling, hence the AWS API DB has to be replicated to handle additional control panel.